# Why angular file download make 2 request and get 2 different response?

Tags: jquery, angularjs

In my app, I am using angular 1.6 currently. I want to make file download and actually I succeed it. Here are some code:

```
object.downloadFileByOwner = function (ownerId) {
        return $http({
            method: "POST",
            url: urlPrefix + "/file/download/by-owner?candidateId=" + candidateId + "&ownerId=" + ownerId,
            headers: headers,
            responseType: 'arraybuffer'
        }).then(function (response) {
            let headers = response.headers;
            headers = headers();

            let filename = headers['filename'];
            let contentType = headers['content-type'];
            let contentDis = headers['content-disposition'];

            let linkElement = document.createElement('a');
            try {
                let blob = new Blob([response.data], { type: contentType });
                let url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);

                linkElement.setAttribute('href', url);
                linkElement.setAttribute("download", filename);

                let clickEvent = new MouseEvent("click", {
                    "view": window,
                    "bubbles": true,
                    "cancelable": false
                });
                linkElement.dispatchEvent(clickEvent);
            } catch (ex) {
                console.log(ex);
            }
        });
    };
```

This is my download function from angular service. But when click file name to download it, browser make 2 request and get 2 different response. 1. response does not contain filename, but 2. one get filename in it. You can find screenshots from browser here. [all images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oTEcg.jpg) 
I want to get filename from headers, but as you can see the variable filename in download function the filename is undefined. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Its CORS, browser make that request to check wheather your server allows cross origin requests,thats why first method is OPTIONS

Comment: So why am I cannot get filename from headers? Actually it is in headers.

Comment: what server side language you are using?

Comment: It is java (spring boot). As you see in last part of image there is filename in headers.

Comment: you can check by setting headers:     header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT');   in your response

Comment: The problem is not cors because i can get file to download. The problem is i cannot get filename, so i want to save file with its real name. By the way i have cors extention on chrome to enable cors.

Comment: your code seems fine to me, for more debugging can you provide a plunkar?

Comment: I will. Thank you

Comment: Why did you choose `responseType: 'arraybuffer'` instead of `responseType: 'blob'`? It would seem more efficient to use the Blob created by the XHR API. Can you explain the extra steps of downloading  'arraybuffer' and converting it to Blob?

Comment: This is my first time to download file with angular. So actually i don't  know the reason.  I just make some research and found this. If you have better solution I will appriciate to use it (with filename, because this is not the problem i asked.).

Comment: How to get the filename in last part of image?

Answer (score 0):

OPTIONS is a `preflight request` not an actual request.

> This method allows the client to determine the options and/or requirements associated with a resource, or the capabilities of a server, without implying a resource action or initiating a resource retrieval.
>
> A CORS preflight request is a CORS request that checks to see if the CORS protocol is understood.
>
> It is an OPTIONS request using two HTTP request headers: Access-Control-Request-Method and Access-Control-Request-Headers, and the Origin header.
>
> A preflight request is automatically issued by a browser when needed; in normal cases, front-end developers don't need to craft such requests themselves.

Reference [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Preflight_request)

Answer (score 0):

@Sibi Raj and @Gaurav Srivastava was right about 1. part of question that is 2 different request. The reason of why i cannot get filename from headers is that my server and clint side are on different domain. So i have to add `"Access-Control-Expose-Headers"` to where server response to me.